# jython float precision after reading oracle wrong

Tags: oracle, jython

i'm having issues with reading floats from oracle. 
i have the following snippet:

```
sqlstr='select prio from tabletest'
statement = None
if connection is not None:
    try:
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlstr)
        if connection is not None:
            rs = statement.executeQuery()
            if rs is not None:
                #statement.closeOnComplete()
                while (rs.next()):
                    NWW = rs.getFloat(1)
                    print (NWW)
                rs.close()
            else:
                statement.close()
  except:
        pass
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

this gets me this:

```
 0.5
 0.5
 0.5
 0.20000000298
 0.5
 0.990000009537
 0.5
 0.5
 0.699999988079
```

but my actual data in the db looks like this:

```
0,5
0,5
0,5
0,2
0,5
0,99
0,5
0,5
0,7
```

the db is defined as:

```
  CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."tabletest" 
   (        "NWW" NUMBER(12,8)
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
```

as you can see, the float are only precise having prio=0.5 ... is there any option I can set that the floats are precise?

thanks,
E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... a bit embarassing, but rs.getDouble(1) solved my issue. :)